# Switching css class for a specific piece of text within a p or span tag

Tags: css, html, tags

I have a `<p>` tag which will contain a few lines of text. The p tag has a css class assigned to it, but I would like to change the text format in some parts of the paragraph.

I used to do this with the `<font>` tag, but I see HTML5 is not supporting it anymore.

What is the best way to do it now?

Example:

```
<p class="mainText">This is a test 
  <font class="newFormat"> for changing the text format</font> 
 within a paragraph.
</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: why don't you use a <span> tag?

Comment: Asking for “best way” tends to be primarily opinion-based, but the question is also too broad and unclear. Nothing has been said about the nature of the texts or about the desired fallback rendering (i.e. what should happen when CSS is off). If you *only* want to change text rendering with *no* idea of any other aspects, then `font` is the most honest markup element (and browsers keep supporting, *as suggested* in HTML5 drafts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the element that has the semantics that best describe the reason you want to change the text style (e.g. `<em>`) with `<span>` being the last resort if nothing is appropriate.

Then write CSS that matches that element in the same way that you currently do for `<font>`.

Comment: Sounds great. But <em> is displaying italic by default and my class is not overriding it even if setting font-style: none; :S

Comment: It's `normal` not `none`.